# How to get total number of Facebook-likes on a photo?

Tags: php, facebook-like, facebook-fql

How to get the total number of facebook likes on all the photos of the user with use of PHP api any suggestions?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9563782/how-can-i-count-the-total-number-of-all-likes-and-comments-on-every-object-on-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose this is possible by querying the [`photo`](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/photo) FQL table and look for the like_info struct, specifically for the like_count. And hence something like the below query should work:

```
SELECT object_id, album_object_id, like_info.like_count FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me()
)
```

This would return something like:

```
Array
(
    [data] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => XXX
                    [album_object_id] => YYY
                    [like_info] => Array
                        (
                            [like_count] => 7
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => XXX
                    [album_object_id] => YYY
                    [like_info] => Array
                        (
                            [like_count] => 9
                        )

                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [object_id] => XXX
                    [album_object_id] => YYY
                    [like_info] => Array
                        (
                            [like_count] => 1
                        )

                )
        )
)
```

From here, it should be a straight forward loop to get the photo(s) with highest number of likes.

---

Update: based on @cpilko addition, this should work:

```
SELECT object_id, album_object_id, like_info.like_count FROM photo WHERE album_object_id IN (
    SELECT object_id FROM album WHERE owner = me()
) ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Add `ORDER BY like_info.like_count DESC LIMIT 1` to the end of @ifaour's query and you'll get only the photo with the highest number of likes.

Comment: You could also simplify the original query to `SELECT object_id, album_object_id, like_info.like_count FROM photo WHERE owner = me()`

Comment: I didn't suggest the short version because it doesn't retrieve all the photos...I guess the tagged photos are not included

Answer (score 1):

I approach it this way:

```
<?php
 // the url to check how many likes
$url = 'url of image';
// build the facebook query
$fburl = "http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='$url'&format=atom";
// grab the atom dump via facebook api url call above
$ch = curl_init($fburl); // url for page
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
$atom_data = curl_exec($ch);
// it returns something like this:
/* <fql_query_response xmlns="http://api.facebook.com/1.0/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" list="true"> 
<link_stat> 
 <like_count>9</like_count> 
</link_stat> 
</fql_query_response>  */  
preg_match('#like_count>(\d+)<#',$atom_data,$matches);
$like_count = $matches[1]; 
echo "The image has ".$like_count." likes on facebook";



// OPTION 2 >>> keeping it to a 1 liner:
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=select%20like_count%20from%20link_stat%20where%20url='$url'&format=json"));
echo "The image has " . $data[0]->like_count . " likes on facebook";

 ?>
```

Comment: i want to get highest no. of likes from all the photos. this will get only a particular url?

Comment: There is no specific way to get just the most liked image with one query/request. You need a loop or series. for more refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7271029/how-to-get-page-photo-with-the-most-likes-comments.